# How set OrderBy on GroupedEnumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

My result set is not sorting.  How do I set up OrderBy for type System.Linq.GroupedEnumerable

I've converted an application from Core 1.1 to 2.2.  Everything ported over fine except one piece of logic that: 
1) takes a response from a service call maps it to a GroupedEnumerable
2) takes the grouped set and passes it to a function that maps it to an object of type System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectEnumerableIterator.

The resulting object is properly populated but not sorted.  I have tried the order by in the function parameter call and as a separate process afterwards.

```
//response = {myService.myClient.SearchNominationsResponse}
//groupedSet = {System.Linq.GroupedEnumerable<ServiceClients.myClient.NominationObject, long>}
//result = {System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectEnumerableIterator<System.Linq.IGrouping<long, ServiceClients.myClient.NominationObject>, app.ViewModels.EvaluationSummary>}

public IEnumerable<EvaluationSummary> GetEvaluationSummaries(string sortBy, string sortOrder, Filter filter = null)
{      
    var request = Mapper.MapSearchNominationRequest(filter);
    request.IsDetailed = false;

    var response = myService.SearchNominationsAsync(request).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    var groupedSet = response.mySet.GroupBy(n => n.SetId);

    // I get a proper result but it is not sorted
    var result = groupedSet.Select(
        g => Mapper.MapEvaluationSummary(
            g.OrderBy(g2 => sortBy + " " + sortOrder)
             .Last()));

    // Still not sorting
    result = result.OrderBy(r => sortBy + sortOrder);
    return result;    
}    

public EvaluationSummary MapEvaluationSummary(SetObject setIn)
{
    var eval = new EvaluationSummary
    {
        setDate = setIn.Date,
        setId = setIn.Id,
        setTypeId = setIn.TypeId,
        setTypeDescription = setIn.TypeDescription,
        setStatusId = setIn.StatusId,
        setStatusDescription = setIn.StatusDescription,
        setBy = setIn.Manager,
        setEmployee = setIn.employee
    };
}
```

So in my view I have columns that list Date, Id, setEmployee.  I can click on these values to issue a sort pattern and I can see that the sortBy and sortOrder variables are being passed in with proper values but the sorting is not happening.

I expect 'William' to appear before 'Bill' and then Bill to appear before 'William' when toggling the employee column header in my view.

Comment: What is the value of `sortBy` and `sortOrder`? Shouldn't you be sorting by a property of the object itself instead of a hard-coded string (which will do nothing, since all items will have the same value)?  `result.OrderBy(r => "some random string")` has no affect on the ordering. `result.OrderBy(r => r.employee.Name)` would sort the items alphabetically by name. ` `result.OrderByDescending(r => r.employee.Name)` would sort the items alphabetically (descending, from Z to A) by name.

Comment: Rufus is correct; this code doesn't make any sense; the sort key has to be *different* for every non-equal value. In your lambda `g2 => something`, the `something` has to somewhere include `g2`!  I am interested to learn how people come to believe false things about LINQ; can you explain the thought process here that got you to specifying a constant sort key? There may be documentation or other educational materials that will help fix that thought process.

Comment: I suspect that you may have some completely wrong idea about what it means to "order by".  Imagine you have a bunch of people.  You say "order yourselves by height", so everyone says what their height is, and then that determines the order.  You say "order yourselves by last name", and everyone says what their last name is, and that determines the order.  You say "order yourselves by weight" and everyone says what their weight is, and that determines the order. But in your scenario you are saying "order yourselves by the word foobar", and so everyone says "foobar" and they don't change order.

Comment: It is the *lambda* that implements the "everyone says what their height is".  That is, for person p, we'd say `p => p.Height`, meaning "every person, call them p, says what their height is, and that's what we're going to order them by".  So the lambda must return some value that is *unique to each member of the group set* if what you want is to sort that group set. If you want to order the groups by size, say, you'd say `g2 => g2.Count()`, and then large groups would come after small groups.

Comment: Ok I can see where you would get that idea. The sortBy is the name of the column / result element. So instead g2.name, the variable resolves to the value name (not.g2.name). The syntax of the order by specifies a concatenated value of sort order (asc or desc). Now remember I said I converted this app from core 1.1 to 2.2. So in 1.1, the developer who originally wrote this code had it working. There is no error (syntax or logic) it just doesn't work. Your answer of g2.element makes sense now I just to figure out how supply a variable for the element name? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Based off of the previous answers, I'm still not sure if I can substitute a property name in the LINQ with a variable.  To fix my problem and move on I've implemented JS logic to sort my table headers.  We had a custom JS that we use to format tables in our apps but it seems the sort functionality never worked.  Anyway not an answer to my question but this is how I solved the problem:

Logic can be found at:
 http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/

-HaYen